# Android ndk-build command failed

Tags: java, android

I have no idea what to do?

any ideas ?
do you need any other files ?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iagrj.jpg)

Comment: same error I am getting, Please anybody do help

Comment: I actually solved it, but i dont know how. But later on i got another error, so i switched the library. I suggest to use the "tess two" library , i used the same and it works fine now :)